# How to schedule a batch file to login to a website

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Each hour, the internet of our school needs to be reconnected by entering the username and password. How we can add a batch file in task scheduler to automate the login?

Answer (score 1):

```
:start
ping -n 1000 127.0.0.1 > nul
    REM call local html with the form info that will submit onload
goto start
```

Replacing 1000 with a higher number, as you cannot `wait` in a batch. This will send x amount of ping to `localhost`. Do some testing to get something close to an hour.

Now for the `html` file, You could save the login page as html,add `value="myUsername"` and `value="myPassword"` to the right input fields.

Adding/using the `name` of the form add `<script>document.formName.submit();</script>` to the very end of the document.

Now keep in mind that the website might validate the `HTTP_REFERER`, in which case this would not work...

Comment: thank you for your help, Kindly yes the website should validate the refer. how can we do that?

Comment: by the referrer I mean where the form was sent from (`HTTP_REFERER` in php), not the username/password combination. You could try to do it manually beforehand, save the login page as html and try to login using the local copy. by changing the `action` of the form to the appropriate URL of the website...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a vbscript to type text in.

```
 Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad.exe"
  WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"

  WshShell.SendKeys "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this guide during my latest googling marathon and it remindeded me of your question ! [therevisionist.org](https://therevisionist.org/software-engineering/vbscript-tutorials/13-vbscript-internet-explorer-html-automation/) It is a vbs, not a batch. Hopefully it will fit the bill !

```
Option Explicit
Dim ie, ipf
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Sub WaitForLoad   
Do While IE.Busy
WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
End Sub

ie.Left = 0
ie.Top = 0
ie.Toolbar = 0
ie.StatusBar = 0
ie.Height = 200
ie.Width = 1020
ie.Resizable = 0

ie.Navigate "https://www.exemple.com/"

Call WaitForLoad 

ie.Visible = True 

ie.Document.All.Item("email").Value="TestEmail@gmail.com"
ie.Document.All.Item("pass").Value="ThePassword"
ie.Document.All.Item("login_form").Submit
```

You could use my previous answer to call the `.vbs` periodically.